# How to handle a question where a feature is now possible?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions, specific-question, etiquette

In May I asked this question [How to specify the location a MVC view will be created for a MVC controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813813/how-to-specify-the-location-a-mvc-view-will-be-created-for-a-mvc-controller) on SO. At the time the answer required a hack to be done since the feature was not supported in MVC 1.

With the latest release of MVC 2 Preview the above feature is implemented as areas, and therefore it can now be done, and since the goal of SO is to keep information new and up to date I would like to update the question to reflect this.

What would the correct procedure be to handle this scenario?

- Make the question a CW, and add the above as an answer?
- Add the above as an answer and make it the accepted answer?
- Ask the question specifying MVC 2 rather the just MVC?
- Edit the question and add the change with a link to MSDN for the new feature?

*I apologize if this has been asked before. I have to admit I could not come up with the right search terms to search for this*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have already accepted an answer, you could do the good community thing and edit their answer to reflect the changes.

Otherwise you could create your own answer to your own question providing the new details and then after some point setting that as the new accepted answer.

I don't think it would be a good idea to fracture off into another question just because it is a different version. As long as you make your original question pretty explicit in the answers (i.e. detailing that the new information is for Version 2) then you shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: The only problem with option one is the edit level required to do such an edit. Sadly I don't have edit ability on SO.

Answer (score 2):

I think the fourth option is best.  Preface the question with an Edit, something like:

> EDIT: The accepted answer to this
>   question was correct at the time,
>   however a new feature has made it
>   easier/more visible to accomplish the
>   goal of the question.  Please see
>   [link to new feature] for more
>   information.

This way, the question remains for anyone who may be working on legacy systems and need the original answer, and we don't get new questions every time some minor feature is upgraded.

Answer (score 2):

This is going to happen more and more as new software is released or information simply becomes obsolete. If the question has already received many (now wrong) answers, simply *evolving* the question and adding new answers might not *always* be the best option.

#### The Pragmatic Approach

If the *vast* majority of old answers suddenly become incorrect, **consider closing the question as "no longer relevant."** Leave a comment in the question as to why it was closed. If the question is still relevant (needing new answers), **re-post the original question** for the community to answer correctly.

This way, the old question (with legacy answers) will remain on the system for legacy users. The new question will receive fresh answers so the **integrity of Stack Overflow as a authoritative, canonical source of information is preserved**.

Everyone wins.

Comment: +1 - The "No longer relevant" approach was *built* for this! Adding new answers to a question for an older version will likely confuse anyone visiting that page in a future.